# Passing formevent and index React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a form with multiple inputs that I am trying to pass both the formevent and index to a function to change an object at a particular index in an array. See below example:

```
const item1={
  Name:""
}


export default function App() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(item1);
  const [itemList,setItemList]=useState([])
  const { Name } = itemName;
  const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setfruit((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
    }));
  const onSubmit =(index)=> (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    //do some action here that references index and form data;
return (
    {itemList.map((item,index)=>{
     <div id='submitted'>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <label className='labels' htmlFor="Name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="Name" value={Name} onChange={onChange} />
        <Button  type="submit">Add Item</Button>
      </form>
})
```

How do I pass both the form submission data and the current index of the map function to the "onSubmit" const? My curried index function doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add index in `onSubmit` like this:

```
onSubmit={onSubmit(index)}
```